# how can i convert data into string format?

Tags: string-manipulation

I have nested-lists in number format,like

```
 data={{1,2,3},{2,{3,4,50}},{4,5,6},{3,{3,{5,6}}}}
```

I want to convert each number into `String` format.For that purpose I tried the following code,but it doesn't working.

case1 :

```
 stringData=ReplaceAll[data, Identity -> String]
```

case2:

stringData= MapAll[ToString, data]

Testcase 1:

```
Part[stringData, 1, 2] + 10
```

I evaluated testcase,but it showing `12`.

How can I solve this?

feel free,If you want to edit my question.

Comment: Look at the docs for `ToString`.

Answer (score 3):

Building on your first try, an alternative to acl's approach is

```
l = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, {3, 4, 50}}, {4, 5, 6}, {3, {3, {5, 6}}}};
ReplaceAll[l, n_Integer :> ToString[n]]
```

which gives

```
{{"1", "2", "3"}, {"2", {"3", "4", "50"}}, {"4", "5", "6"}, {"3", {"3", {"5", "6"}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does `Map` like this

```
Map[
 ToString[#] &,
 {{1, 2, 3}, {2, {3, 4, 50}}, {4, 5, 6}, {3, {3, {5, 6}}}},
 {-1}
 ]
```

do what you want?

Comment: Why do you use `ToString[#] &`, instead of just `ToString`?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries to annoy MrW with my lack of brevity :)

Comment: @acl Ah, then why not `Function[string, ToString[string]][#]&` :P

Comment: @rm-rf He ought then to prefer `ToString[#] & @# &@# &@# &@# &@# &@# &@# &@# &@# &`.  Oh, sorry, that's too compact: how about `ToString[#] &[#] &[#] &[#] &[#] &[#] &[#] &[#] &[#] &[#] &[#] &` instead? :-)

Comment: Oh gads, I've been [sniped](http://xkcd.com/356/).  I was about to comment on the unnecessary `Function` in `ToString[#] &` and then I saw the comments.  I hate you for the next 13.7 minutes. ;-p